# tkinter Problem: When an if conditional is wrong but still right?

Tags: python, tkinter

tl,dr: An if conditional is activated when I know the condition is not TRUE.

This is probably a question about python in general, but I came across this using tkinter, so i'm sticking with that. I was trying to understand code I got from here, when I found this problem (I stripped it down to make it plain):

```
import tkinter as tk

after_id = None

def post():
    global after_id
    if after_id:
        print('How can this print if \"after_id == True\" is ' + str(after_id == True))
        
root = customtkinter.CTk()
after_id = root.after(500, post)

root.mainloop()
```

Evidently, this does print, and as you can see, after_id is not TRUE, it is not even Boolean. This sort of flies against everything I thought I knew about if statements. Can someone please explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: Objects in Python don't have to be Booleans in order to be True or False. In fact, most objects in Python are "truthy", except things like `None`, `False`, `0`, and a few [others](https://www.humaneer.org/python3/truthiness-in-python/). `after_id` evaluates as `True` because it has a value that is presumably not `None` or `0`, etc. What value are you actually seeing for `after_id`?

Comment: Yeah, the root of this is the value of `after_id`. I tried your code, and added a `print(after_id)` after the `global after_id` call... and seems I got `after#0` as the output.  Where that is coming from, I do not know, and leave to someone else to answer.

Comment: Thanks JRiggles and Gertlex. I figured this out like right after I posted.

Answer (score 2):

I just learned that all string statements except for an empty string are considered true in python. This is true for many non-empty objects apparently. Hope I didn't waste anyones time.

Answer (score 1):

In python, an object undergoes a [truth testing procedure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). Here is the procedure (Taken from python docs):

## Truth Testing Procedure

By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a **bool**() method that returns False or a **len**() method that returns zero, when called with the object. Here are most of the built-in objects considered false:

1. constants defined to be false: None and False.
2. zero of any numeric type: 0, 0.0, 0j, Decimal(0), Fraction(0, 1)
3. empty sequences and collections: '', (), [], {}, set(), range(0)

Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return 0 or False for false and 1 or True for true, unless otherwise stated.

## Solution

Ssince you are passing an object in the condition, the python interpreter interprets it as True like most other objects except those mentioned and thus runs the code in the `if` block of code.